# PHP 5.4 array throwing syntax error

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.4

I have the following PHP method in a class:

```
function pullMsg() {
    $msgOut = [];
    if (count($this->msgQin) > 0) {
        $msg = array_pop($this->msgQin);
        $msgArr = explode('::', msg);
        $msgOut['sender'] = msgArr[0];
        $msgOut['timestamp'] = msgArr[1];
        $msgOut['message'] = msgArr[2];
    }
    return $msgOut;
}
```

I have one machine, running PHP 5.6 that is using this class and has no problem with it. But on a machine running PHP 5.4, including this file throws up the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/intranet/lib/libIpcMessaging.php on line 77
```

Line 77 in this case is: $msgOut['sender'] = msgArr[0]; – ie, the first time I try to assign a value to a member of the array. Bear in mind this error doesn't occur when the method is called - it happens immediately the file is included. Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot your `$` for your variable names

Comment: Doh! Thanks for that. I've been staring at this for ages... Weird that only one of the machines picked it up, though. I'll go compare the php.ini settings...